# discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10011): Unknown Role

Tags: python, discord.py

This seems like a popular error, but I can't for the life of me find a fix that'll work for me. I'm trying to give a member a role whenever they join my server but every time it reaches `await member.add_roles(member, role)` it sends off the error in the title. I've tried testing in the `on_message` function with the exact same results.

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from replit import db


client = discord.Client()

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot('PREFIX',intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("I'm in")
  print(client.user)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):

  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.content == "ping":
    await message.channel.send("pong")


@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f"{member} has joined")
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Member")
    await member.add_roles(member, role)



   
client.run(token)
```

Comment: It looks like Member is not a role

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
print(f"{member} has joined")
role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Member")
await member.add_roles(member, role) # member argument is causing issue, remove that
```

member is `discord.Member` object, if you put that in add_roles, it will error out and throw `discord.NotFound 404`

```py
print(f"{member} has joined")
role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Member")
await member.add_roles(role)
```

also consider getting rid of that `client = discord.Client()` line, it's quite useless